# send dummy logs to my docker fluentbit agent

Tags: fluent-bit

I have installed fluentbit agent on my docker and also exposed the port 24224 to my localhost.

`How do I send a dummy log to my fluentbit docker agent ?`

For what I understand is when I will send a log to :24224 somehow, the agent will do some processing on logs and will send it to localhost:8006
which should be captured in my otel-collector.

I have done all the setup, all I missing is -- a dummy log to test the scenario.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker run --log-driver=fluentd -t ubuntu echo "Testing a log message"`

The command is mostly self explanatory for docker users, I have added a description for the ease of understanding.

---

The command simply follows docker run syntax

`docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND]`

`IMAGE=ubuntu`
This command simply uses the `ubuntu` docker image.

`COMMAND= echo "Testing a log message"`
runs the basic `echo` command.

the main helpful portion is `log-driver`

Appearantly, ubuntu docker image supports several log drivers, this list also includes fluend -- which will automatically send the message to localhost:24224 without specifying port !

---

There might be other tools which can be configured to send logs to localhost:24224, this is one of those many solutions which came handy !

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and explain why it answers the question.  Perhaps explain what each of the option flags does.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @alexpdev, I have added desciption as per your suggestion

Comment: Thanks! Much better.  Somebody had flagged your answer for deletion, that is why I asked.